# не работает while помогите

Tags: python, python-3.8

щас изучаю укус питона, пробую код, он не работает.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:/mmm/gotokod/sadadfwa.py", line 1, in 
while running:
NameError: name 'running' is not defined

код:

```
while running:
    guess = int(input('Введите целое число : '))
    if guess == number:
        print('Поздравляю, вы угадали.')
        running = False # это останавливает цикл while
    elif guess < number:
        print('Нет, загаданное число немного больше этого')
    else:
        print('Нет, загаданное число немного меньше этого.')
else:
    print('Цикл while закончен.')
# Здесь можете выполнить всё что вам ещё нужно
print('Завершение.')
```

пайтон 3.8.5 архитектура 32

Comment: Что непонятным для вас осталось в сообщении "Имя 'running' не определено"?

Comment: Вы не определили `running`m допишите в начало строку `running = True` или `False`

Answer (score 1):

В питоне прежде чем читать переменную ей нужно присвоить значение. Например вот ошибочный код:

```py
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> running
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'running' is not defined
```

А вот корректный:

```py
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> running = True
>>> running
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае вы пытаетесь использовать переменную `running` до присвоения ей какого - то значения. Вы можете перед своим кодом вставить строку

```py
running = True
```

И код заработает